# What video codecs have most amount of content and thus popular at present/in future?

Tags: video-encoding

I want to find out if I can get some data on the percentage wise distribution of video content, for different video codecs currently used for video encoding. I know there are different applications/use-case scenarios which have different encoder used but i want to consdier all that and have a overall usage number(%)

My guess is(highest to lowest % of content) -

- H.264(AVC)
- DivX
- MPEG2
- VP6

  Where do H.263, MPEG4, VC-1, RV, Theora, etc. fit in here.

How may this look like in future?

PS:I would like this to be community wiki to have get wider range of inputs, if someone with privileges can do it for me please.

thank you.

-AD

Comment: The future is uncertain - *this* format war isn't over, far from it; we may see a few surprises yet (as we have in other similar cases).

Comment: I would say that VC-1 falls just under MPEG2 and Theora just above VP6 - for now. RV seems pretty esoteric and would place it even lower than VC-1. DivX is just a container around MPEG4/H.264, so you could lump those in with H.264.

Comment: So can i say it could be like - H.264 , VP6/VP8, DivX , MPEG2, VC1, Theora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that `WebM` format (which is actually VP8) which is part of the [WebM Project](http://www.webmproject.org/) will see a rise since YouTube is encoding all of the videos in `WebM` format as an alternative.

Comment: @robin hood, yep missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

I vote for WebM as a better quality and freer alternative to H.264